# Background image on selected li by css

Tags: html, css

my issue is: Can I apply a background-image to a selectioned `<li>` that contain a link, only by css? Now by this:

```
.art-block  li:hover , .art-block  li:visited
{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

I can only apply a background  when mouse is over the link but if I move the mouse background desappear.

Comment: not without javascript

Comment: Do you want the background on the `li` element when you mouse over the `a` element within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a only CSS way but here is the JQuery way:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FExhL/)

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why not use `.toggleClass` (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: @JustusRomijn with `toggleClass` you can have more than one active item. http://jsfiddle.net/FExhL/1/